# How to move to the next record on Teltonika Codec 8 protocol for GPS tracking beyond record 13?

Tags: python, server, communication, teltonika

I am currently building a server for GPS tracking using Teltonika **Codec 8 protocol**. While I have read all the relevant documentation, I am facing an issue where I am **unable to move** to the **next record** beyond record 13. I have **received** the **IMEI** and **AVL packet** successfully, but the protocol seems to be stuck at record 13.

**Code: **

`def handle_client(conn, addr):

```
print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

connected = True

while connected:
    imei = conn.recv(1024)
    print(imei)

    try:


        message = '\x01'

        message = message.encode('utf-8')

        conn.send(message)
        connected = False

    except socket.error as e:

        print(f"Error sending reply. Maybe it's not our device {addr}: {e}")
        connected = False



    try:

        data = conn.recv(1024)

        recieved = binascii.hexlify(data)

        print(data)
        print(recieved)

        decodethis(recieved)

        record = getrecord(recieved)

        message = "0000" + str(record).zfill(4)
        print(record)


        message = message.encode('utf-8')

        conn.send(message)
        conn.close()
        connected = False

    except socket.error as e:
        print(f"Error receiving data from {addr}: {e}")
        print("Error Occured.")
        connected = False

        break

conn.close()`
```

I have consulted the documentation and found that I need to send **"00000013"** to inform the protocol that I have received the 13th record. However, I am unsure how to proceed with this. Could someone please provide me with some guidance or sample code to help me move to the next record beyond record 13?

**Followed these links:**
https://community.teltonika-gps.com/4965/how-to-read-data-from-teltonika-fmb001-with-a-python-script
https://wiki.teltonika-networks.com/view/VCode#Codec_8

**Devices:**
FMB110
FMB140

**Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.**

Answer (score 1):

Do you ask what response send to device for inform it that 13 records are received?
Probably You need to send 4 bytes 0x0000000D which means 13 decimal.